# Accesing configuration from callback (mqtt)

Tags: c, mqtt

excuse my english.

The code:
https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTAsync/html/subscribe.html

I working on modify this example, my problem its onConnect callback i want to supply the TOPIC (previous load from a config file) or in this example:

https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/mqttdoc/MQTTAsync/html/publish.html

In the example shown they use #define

```
...
#define TOPIC       "MQTT Examples"
...
void onConnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{
...
        if ((rc = MQTTAsync_subscribe(client, TOPIC, QOS, &opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
...
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
...
        MQTTAsync_setCallbacks(client, NULL, connlost, msgarrvd, NULL);
...
        conn_opts.onSuccess = onConnect;
        conn_opts.onFailure = onConnectFailure;
        conn_opts.context = client;
        if ((rc = MQTTAsync_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS)
        {
                printf("Failed to start connect, return code %d\n", rc);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
...
```

My question its, what its the most correct way for doing this? using global variables?

Thanks

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Post your code (MCVE) don't point to it.

Comment: my code actually its exactly like the link code, i trying to known the best way for doing that before doing it. Its a concept problem.

Comment: [Edit] your post and include whatever code represents the concept(s) you are asking about. Links rot, posted code will be there until this thread is deleted. Take my advice; [tour], [Ask], and [MCVE]. Otherwise your post will receive multiple down-votes and likely wind up being removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve my problem, i think its the best way (if not feedback welcome)

```
typedef struct mqtt_context{
    MQTTAsync client;
    char *MQTT_Broker_Addr;
    char *Username;
    char *Password;
    char *ClientID;
    char *Payload;
    int Qos;
} mqtt_context;

void onConnect(void* context, MQTTAsync_successData* response)
{

    mqtt_context *ctx = (mqtt_context *)context;
    MQTTAsync_responseOptions ropts = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;
    ropts.context = ctx;

    MQTTAsync_subscribe(ctx->client, ctx->Topic, ctx->Qos, &ropts);

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    mqtt_context *ctx = g_malloc0(sizeof(struct mqtt_context));

    ctx->MQTT_Broker_Addr = g_strdup ("xxx");

    ctx->ClientID = "ExampleClientSub";
    ctx->Username = "xxxxxx";
    ctx->Password = "xxxx";
...

 MQTTAsync_setCallbacks(ctx->client, ctx, connlost, msgarrvd, NULL)
...
 MQTTAsync_connect(ctx->client, &conn_opts)
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can either use a global variable or load the config file inside the on_connect function. Using global variable is more efficient because you will have to load the config file only once.

Comment: i known i can use global variables, but normally using "global variables" aren't the   most correct way.

Comment: i still reading about the topic, and i think i found the "correct way"  in this case, the "trick" its using "void *context", not global variables. Unfortunately i could not find any examples (or good and clearly docs for a newbie) but tomorrow would work on this.

Comment: The most correct way is what satisfies your boss. If he/she is against globals, do as he wants to. Otherwise, do what is simplest and quickest.